# Openings in 3 phase distribution box cover?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, meter

I live in rural Indiana. I have a standalone woodshop. Since I have 3 phase equipment, I installed a converter and use a 3 phase distribution box to send power to each machine via a dedicated fused circuit. Attached is a picture of the distribution box next to the electrical panel.
[image: 3 phase distribution box on right]
[image: Inside of distribution box]

I would like to add 3 panel mount readout displays for V, I & Hz. I need a 22mm hole in the front cover to instal these. Here us a pic of this device.
[image]

Is it okay to do this? I do not know about codes that may apply here.

Comment: Are the items UL-Listed (e.g. from Grainger or Digi-Key)?  Or are they cheap Chinese (3rd party seller on Amazon etc.)

Comment: These conform to European CE standard and IEC 947-5-1. Got them from UK when I was there. Only tested one and it shows same voltage and current as my meters. Very happy with performance. I just wanted to know if it is okay to install them in the panel cover. I actually saw them installed as such and thought it would be good to know that my converter is putting good voltage out and the current is balanced on all phases.

Comment: I don't suppose they have the BSI kite mark? CE is an "honor system" self-certification: in the US the item must be "approved" (NEC 110.2), which means literally by your local inspector, but in practice by an NRTL.  BSI is the predominant NRTL in Britain.  I'd love to find a legal source for things like that.

Comment: I live in rural area, no inspections were required 20 yrs ago when I built. However, since I wired the shop myself, I had it inspected. Do you know the answer to my question? Ignoring the device origin, is it okay to install such readout display in the box cover?

Comment: @ImranMalik -- is there a reason you're using a funky fuseblock setup for 3ph distribution instead of an ordinary 3ph loadcenter?

Comment: LOL, I built a RPC and all parts came from a used electrical supplier. I told home what I would like to do and he pulled the parts for me. This was 20 yrs ago and the whole thing cost me under $500. This included 10HP motor and AB size1 magnetic motor starter.

Comment: What is up with the 12 Ga. cables here? Do they serve one device? It's a code violation to have the current-carrying conductors for one device in separate cables. Where does the second black wire (that disappears to the left) go / what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Must be approved

NEC 110.2 is specific on this: the items must be approved for use.  Literally it means by the local inspector (which gives the inspector latitude/flex), however with the country awash in cheap Cheese junk off Amazon and eBay, inspectors will generally want to see the mark of an independent 3rd party NRTL (Nationally Recognized Testing Lab).  UL, ETL, CSA, BSI, TUV, and the like.

CE is an "honor system" self-certification where the manufacturer signs a paper. That only works if EU authorities can meaningfully sanction the company making or importing it. Otherwise, CE is universally faked; everything on Alibaba has "CE" and almost none of it would pass 3rd party testing.

### It goes in a *1/2" trade-size* knockout

which is a 7/8" hole.

It can be mounted on the door, or a separate enclosure of some kind linked by metal conduit to this one.

### Installation must be tidy.

NEC 110.12 requires "neat and workmanlike" installation.  In this case, you'll need to groom the wires so they aren't a "science project" nightmare when you open the box.   So the wires will need to be gathered and controlled so the box is tidy.

Probably the right way to do that is with (typically white) spiral wire loom, anchored with a clamp on the door near the top. Then running vertically, right next to the hinge for some distance (maybe 6 inches), Then anchored with a clamp in the box, then onward as far as possible in loom before splitting.

Thus, when the door is opened or closed the wires are not being bent, at all. The whole bundle is being twisted 90 degrees, which stranded wire can handle just fine.  The loom also is a spiral and doesn't mind being given a 90 degree twist.

### Panel *working space* needs to be restored

It did not pass inspection as pictured.

Panels require a *working space* of the width of the panel(s) (but at least 30"), 36" depth/standback room, a stable flat floor, and 78" (6'6") of headroom above the floor.

**This area must be kept clear at all times**.

As such, the item storage needs to find another home, and the dust collector pipes need to find another route e.g. overhead.

Also the yellow cable stapled to the wall, if AC power, must be replaced with in-wall wiring such as Romex. See NEC 400.8.   No shop was ever made worse by conduit in or on the walls.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You are correct about space around the panel. Machine got moved there along with the dust collection. I cannot recall if I already had the 3 phase distribution box installed it not at the time of the inspection. I will try to be tidy in the install if these readout displays. I understand the comment regarding device approval.